# How to remove elements from jquery object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a specific problem. I want to grab some element, traverse through it and remove or edit unwanted elements before posting that element data over JSON.

My function looks like this.

```
$("#submit_btn").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        pdfhtml = $("#Calculation").html();
        var inputs = $("input[type=number]", pdfhtml);

        $.each(inputs, function(k, v) {
            $(this).remove();
            //$(this, pdfhtml).remove(); //also not working
        })

        var data = {};
        data["data"] = pdfhtml;
        alert(pdfhtml);
        getdataJSON("","POST", "html", data, true); 
    });
```

The problem I have is that nothing happens, elements are still present after i submit this data. What am I doing wrong? I need this in order to generate pdf with mpdf6 (PHP).

Comment: In addition if I put alert inside that each like this alert($(this).val()); I always get alert of each input value ;) but remove() doesn't work. I don't know how else can I manipulate fileds. I need to get rid of some helper divs and input element. Actually i only need value ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery won't do string modification like that. All `inputs` will be is an in-memory representation of `<input>` tags, changes to these will not save back to the `pdfhtml` string.

What you should do instead is clone the `#Calculation` div, then perform your actions:

```
$("#submit_btn").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var pdfhtml = $("#Calculation").clone(); // Clone this
    var inputs = pdfhtml.find("input[type=number]");

    $.each(inputs, function(k, v) {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    var data = {};
    data["data"] = pdfhtml.html(); // Read the HTML here...
    alert(pdfhtml);
    getdataJSON("","POST", "html", data, true); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for solution with $.each and clone(). I will use this one, because it suits me better.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget, you don't really need the `$.each` either, `pdfhtml.find("input[type=number]").remove()` would work fine :)

Comment: I need each, because I need to grab each input value and put it in another div, since on PDF I need the quantity of the products. But thanks for info, because I will need to remove some helper divs, from which I don't need to keep any data ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a temp jQuery object and is removing inputs form that but the original string `pdfhtml` is not modified

```
$("#submit_btn").off("click").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //create a temp dom structure with the target html as its content
    var $temp = $('<div />', {
        html: $("#Calculation").html()
    });

    //modify the temp dom structure
    $temp.find("input[type=number]").remove();

    var data = {};
    //get the update html content from the temp object
    data["data"] = $temp.html();
    alert(pdfhtml);
    getdataJSON("", "POST", "html", data, true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I really couldn't realize I was manipulating wrong string.